# Search for name in arraylist and display all of it

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way to search for certain name and display it for arraylist? (like getting a key from hashmap)

The list format is

Name: score -age

```
{A: 100 - 15, A: 200 - 16, B: 75 -11}
```

and what I want to do is, getting only A's data and displaying it.

```
List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();
scores.add(new Score("A", 100, 15));
scores.add(new Score("A", 200, 16));
scores.add(new Score("B", 75, 11));
```

Comment: Just loop through the `ArrayList`, for each element check if the name is what you're looking for, if yes, then print what you want to print.

Comment: What is this question? Is it homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for `ArrayList` you need to traverse your list and find respective `score element` and show it.

```
List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();    
for(Score score : scores) {
    if (score.getName().equals("A")) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop thru your list, and i hope you have a getter for your properties in your Score class. call the getName() and check if the name is equal to the input name.

```
List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();    
for(Score s: scores){
if("yourinputstr".equals(s.getName())){
System.out.println(s);//you'd have to override toString in your score class to show name, age and score 
}

}
```

Comment: for NP safety, I'd reverse the strings `if("yournameinput".equals(s.getName()))`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your Score class is

```
public class Score
{
   public String str1;
   public int num1;
   public int num2;
}
```

then you can do like this

```
for(Score scr : scores)
{
   if(scr.str1.equals("A")) 
   {
       //do some job
   }
}
```